# Question about the derivation on a particular expected value

Tags: probability

I'm trying to learn why the expected value of this game was calculated the way it was.

Game $\textbf{A}$ is defined by tossing a biased coin $C_1$ that offers a probability of winning (Heads), $P_1=1/2-\alpha$, and a probability of losing (Tails), $1-P_1=1/2+\alpha$, where $0\leq\alpha\leq1/2$ represents the bias against the player. Obviously, the condition for $\textbf{A}$ to be fair is $P_1=1/2$.

The expected value of game $\textbf{A}$ is $$E(\textbf{A})=\frac{P_1-(1-P_1)}{P_1+(1-P_1)}=(1/2-\alpha)-(1/2+\alpha)=-2\alpha.$$

I understand as much that if this was a fair game, $\alpha=0$ and therefore $E(\textbf{A})=0$, but why is that the initial step is the fraction as written?

---

- Richard Epstein, 
  [The Theory of Gambling and Statistical Logic](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Theory_of_Gambling_and_Statistical_L.html?id=8irb9D8_cosC)

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is $$P(\text{heads}) \cdot (\text{value of heads}) + P(\text{tails}) \cdot (\text{value of tails}).$$
Here there is some assumption that winning has a value of $+1$ and losing has a value of $-1$. If you plug this in, you'll get the same result as the book.

More generally, expected value is $\sum P(\text{outcome})\cdot(\text{value of outcome})$ where the sum is over all outcomes.

Comment: I understand where the $(1/2-\alpha)-(1/2+\alpha)$ comes from, but I don't see why the author began the string of equalities with the fraction. I'm curious as to where that comes from.